# Loop to download CSV, takes only last value (last url of the list)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am quite new here but I think you could help me with a basic thing (a loop).

Basically, my scripts runs well but when I open the outputs (.csv files) I see that it took only the last url of the list.

```
for url in urls:
   for jobboard_name in jobboard_names:
       jobboard_name = requests.get(url)
       for file_name in files_names:
           file = open(file_name, "wb")    
           file.write(jobboard_name.content)
           os.replace(file_name,today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + "/" + file_name)
```

Do you have an idea what I need to implement here? I would like to take all the elements of the list "urls"?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: it is because you open the file in write mode with `file = open(file_name, "wb")` so it overwrites everytime, use the `a` flag to open in append mode `file = open(file_name, "ab")`

Comment: Maybe just need to close file before working with it. file.close() before os.replace(...)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! I tried both solutions, but the outputs only take the last url. Really weird..

Answer (score 1):

Opening in write binary mode `"wb"` writes over the file every time you open it. You want to open it in append binary mode `"ab"` instead:

```
for file_name in files_names:
    file = open(file_name, "ab")
```

Alternatively, you could create new files and write binary to them like so (which may be easier than renaming your original files):

```
for url in urls:
   for jobboard_name in jobboard_names:
       jobboard_name = requests.get(url)
       for file_name in files_names:
           with open(today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + "/" + file_name, "wb") as file:    
               file.write(jobboard_name.content)
```

As @joao pointed out, `for jobboard_name in jobboard_names` may be the problem - since it doesn't appear to exist (I assumed you had it higher up), all you'll do is write the same file over and over. To avoid that we can modify your original code like so:

```
for url in urls:
       jobboard_name = requests.get(url)
       for file_name in files_names:
           with open(file_name, "ab") as file:   
               file.write(jobboard_name.content)
           os.replace(file_name,today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + "/" + file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you !! The thing is, when I run my script, I have a TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 32, in <module>
    file.write(jobboard_name.content)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: @drop please see my edit, I think this may be easier

Comment: Thank you for your code. I don't have anymore errors but It still taking the last url only. My urls list is like this: urls = ["https://exemple.com/file1.csv", "https://exemple.com/anotherfile.csv" ] When I try to loop it and only print the urls I can see both urls. However, when the loops executes, it only takes the last url.

Comment: This solution still has the same problem: for every url, the file names are the same, so each iteration overwrites the previous one. You need to write with "ab" mode for appending.

Comment: @drop, are you aware that the `for jobboard_name in jobboard_names:` serves no purpose ? It will just cause the code below to run several times, downloading the same url and overwriting the same file.

Comment: @joao I guess I (incorrectly) assumed they had a higher list of `jobboard_names`. I edited it for "ab"

Comment: @drop I think joao may be right - please see further edits

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. Unfortunately, I still have only the last URL. I will play around and try to figure it out. I still learning :)